# Testing box application from virtual machine

Tags: oauth, network-programming, virtual-machine, box

Box requires you to use HTTPS for any URL other than localhost. Unfortunately, I developed on a Linux virtual machine running inside a Windows machine, and I want to access the server running on Linux from a browser in Windows. Therefore, I cannot use localhost.

Is there a way that I test out my box application without needing to create a certificate on my Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use an SSH tunnel.

1. Set up an SSH server on the Linux machine (make sure you secure it if it's accessible from the Internet)
2. Use a Windows SSH client (like plink or cygwin's SSH client) to create a tunnel to the desired port (80?) of the Linux box. For example, if you're using plink:

`C:\>plink.exe -L 1234:127.0.0.1:80 <username>@<Linux machine IP>`

using cygwin, the command would be the same:

`$ ssh -L 1234:127.0.01:80 <username>@<Linux machine IP>`

This will establish a tunnel between the Windows machine's local port 1234 (127.0.0.1:1234) and the Linux machines port 80 (127.0.0.1:80). So if you open a browser on the Windows machine and point it to 127.0.0.1:1234, you'll really be connecting to 127.0.0.1:80 of the Linux machine.

There are some nice tutorials on SSH tunnels, but make sure you're reading about the right type of tunnel. They come in 3 forms - Local (`-L`), Remote (`-R`) and Dynamic (`-D`). You need the local one.

To debug the tunnel, you can use `nc`. Use something like `nc -l 127.0.0.1 80` to get `nc` to listen on 127.0.0.1:80, then try using the tunnel from the Windows browser. You should see the HTTP request in `nc`.

Comment: This worked, but I had to change the command to `plink.exe -L 127.0.0.1:80:<linux machine IP >:1234 <username>@<Linux machine IP>`